# Handling large map data via HTTP

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

How does one effectively send a large amount of map data via HTTP for the client to render? There appears to be a much better method than delivering a [JSON file with all of the map data](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/data.json). I am curious how large websites such as Apartments.com or Foursquare deliver their map data on a "need to know" basis.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, these large sites "lazy load" it.  Basically, this means even though it's a large data set, they only download the relevant items at a time, and when you sort, page through, etc, they load more.  So, you could have millions of rows, but only actually handle a very small subset at a time.

If you google lazy loading, you should find a lot of examples.

Comment: Thank you. This definitely seems to be what I am looking for. I have found some examples of lazy loading the Google Map itself, but I haven't found much about lazy loading markers. If  you happen to know more about this, please share.

Comment: You could try paging them depending on your use case: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search-pagination - if you need to load them all lazily, you'd probably have to do it by geocode through a custom algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Where the data for a map layer is large, there are a few options you may want to consider:

1. Only transfer about a screen's worth of data at a time. (With this approach, it can be useful to also include a buffer around the screen so you don't have to refresh the data if the user pans a small distance.) I've used this on a previous project, and it's fine for low- to medium-density layers.

   You may want to introduce scale triggers for dense layers so you don't render too much. It's relatively simple to write an AJAX-based layer system. Ours ended up being a few dozen lines and mainly involved responding to map zoom and move events, invalidating the layer if the user uncovered an unloaded area, and handling the AJAX requests to a web service which returned GeoJSON.

   You'll obviously also have to deal with passing in the spatial bounds you're interested in, but all spatial databases have support for requesting just a small section of the total dataset. You may have to play with your spatial indexing if you have performance issues - I had to do some tweaks for a very dense layer which was stored in SQL Server, for example.
2. Cluster map data depending on your zoom level. Although modern web mapping engines are powerful, even the best can become slow when you're trying to render thousands of markers on a layer. Use clustering to combine elements in close proximity, improve performance and create a cleaner-looking map. [Leaflet's MarkerCluster plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) is a good example of this.
3. If all else fails, you can try tile-based rendering with a UTFGrid approach for the interactive layer data. This splits up the underlying map data into tiles of a uniform size - say 256x256 pixels - and behind the scenes the data is modelled as a character grid. For example, an 'X' could correspond to a certain population density. These grids can be relatively expensive to create, but they're very open to aggressive caching if your data is static; you can even pregenerate the whole map's worth of UTFGrid data in advance.

There's a nice introduction to UTFGrids here: http://blog.perrygeo.net/2012/02/24/utfgrids-with-openlayers-and-tilestache/

Mapnik and Tilestache can produce UTFGrids from a given polygon + data source, or it's relatively easy to write your own.

Comment: any idea or reference on how can one achieve the option 1 of yours using Node and MongoDB?
(eg: sending bounds and zoom layer from front-end and getting geojson features for that particular view bounds)